# Existe necessidade de fazer algo para garantir entrega para fila (SQS) na AWS?

Tags: amazon-aws, microsserviços, fila

Supondo que tenho 2 microserviços "A" e "B" que estão se comunicando por meio de uma fila SQS "F".

O microserviço "A" pode cair, "B" também pode cair, a pergunta é: eu deveria levar em consideração que "F" também poderia cair?

Se eu levar em consideração que "F" pode cair, eu poderia fazer algo como colocar a mensagem a ser enviada em uma tabela no banco e fazer o envio assíncrono via job para "F", mas isto parece um overengineering.

Segundo o link https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sqs/faqs/ a AWS diz assim: "As filas padrão oferecem entrega pelo menos uma vez, ou seja, cada mensagem é entregue pelo menos uma vez."

Eu deveria apenas confiar na disponibilidade do SQS e rastrear caso algo não for enviado ao invés de fazer algo para "garantir a entrega" para "F"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente não é necessário rastrear as entregas de mensagens, e seria muito difícil fazê-lo mais eficientemente que o SQS. Se precisar de maior controle no consumo de mensagens, talvez seja mais interessante considerar outros serviços, como o Amazon Kinesis. Note também que o limite de retenção de mensagens no SQS é de 14 dias, as mensagens precisam ser consumidas neste período.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta amigo. Entendo seu ponto e concordo contigo sobre a rastreabilidade, meu ponto é mais sobre a garantia de entrega da mensagem. Se eu não precisar me preocupar com a disponibilidade do SQS, eu não precisaria fazer o rastreamento também. Em um cenário onde não é possível  perder mensagens entre um microserviço e outro, deveria apenas confiar de boas na disponibilidade do SQS ou usar Kinesis, como você sugeriu, ou mesmo o Kafka, por exemplo?

Comment: Uma vez que o cliente envia a mensagem, o SQS a armazena em varias zonas de disponibilidade automaticamente. Não existe uma garantia ou SLA no sentido legal, mas o risco de perder uma mensagem é desprezível tecnicamente. O problema é mais do lado da sua aplicação. E se ela tiver um bug e precisar reprocessar as mensagens? E se não conseguir processar mensagens rapido o suficiente? Ai os streams do Kinesis oferecem mais funcionalidades que uma fila do SQS.

Comment: Show... ótimo ponto, eu já estou levando em consideração que os serviços A ou B irão cair. Eu apenas gostaria de fazer uma comunicação simples via fila entre 2 microserviços e ter certeza que uma mensagem irá chegar no destino. A AWS diz que se ela respondeu OK quando foi postado na fila, irá chegar na fila... mas mesmo "desprezivel tecnicamente", pode acontecer de ela não responder OK e aí bastaria eu enviar novamente e a "garantia" de entrega de mensagem na fila estaria resolvido. Faz sentido amigo?

Comment: Para o SQS não responder OK ele teria que estar indisponível, o que requer a falha simultania de multiplas zonas de disponibilidade. Ate onde eu sei, isso nunca aconteceu e tanto a Amazon quanto diversos clientes utilizam o SQS intensamente. Se quiser ir além disso, teria quer considerar uma arquitetura multi-regioes, o que dificilmente compensa para um caso como descreves.

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Seus comentários me ajudaram bastante. A conclusão é que realmente é um overengineering criar algo para enviar para o SQS em caso de falha, já que uma msg do SQS é salva em várias zonas de disponibilidade. Esta info está em "https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sqs/". Na hora de desenvolver definimos uma region do SQS e eu não estava entendendo onde estavam estas várias zonas, mas lendo "https://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net/pt/wp/AWS_Cloud_Best_Practices_05252010.pdf" entendi que uma region tem várias zonas, algumas tem duas outras tem mais, mas a mágia está aí. Muito obrigado =)

Comment: Isso! Mais detalhes sobra a infraestrutura global da AWS nessa pagina https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/ e recomendo também essa apresentação https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyOAjFNPAbA